# Calculadora en tkinter

Tags: python, poo, tkinter

Amigos, estoy intentando hacer una calculadora sencilla en python con Tkinter, sin embargo y aunque casi todo esta listo, simplemente me dice que los números que ingreso no pueden ser convertidos a float.

Probé dejando todo en String y simplemente no me salía nada, el espacio para el resultado se quedaba vacío y en blanco, fue hecho en POO y cada operación tiene una función, los botones tuve que dejarlos fuera de la función widget para que el texto que tuviera fuera distinto en cada frame. ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Dejo el codigo:

```
**from tkinter import *

class Op:
    def __init__(self, master):
        
        frame2 = Frame(master)
        frame2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        frame2.config(bg="blue")
        frame2.config(width=320, height=170)
        self.btn1=Button(frame2, text="Sumar", command=self.fSuma)
        self.btn1.place(x=230,y=50,width=80, height=30)
        self.widget(frame2)

        frame3 = Frame(master)
        frame3.grid(row=1, column=2)
        frame3.config(bg="red")
        frame3.config(width=320, height=170)
        self.btn1=Button(frame3, text="Restar", command=self.fResta)
        self.btn1.place(x=230,y=50,width=80, height=30)
        self.widget(frame3)

        frame4 = Frame(master)
        frame4.grid(row=2, column=1)
        frame4.config(bg="green")
        frame4.config(width=320, height=170)
        self.btn1=Button(frame4, text="Multiplicacion", command=self.fMultiplicacion)
        self.btn1.place(x=230,y=50,width=80, height=30)
        self.widget(frame4)

        frame5 = Frame(master)
        frame5.grid(row=2, column=2)
        frame5.config(bg="black")
        frame5.config(width=320, height=170)
        self.btn1=Button(frame5, text="Division", command=self.fDivision)
        self.btn1.place(x=230,y=50,width=80, height=30)
        self.widget(frame5)

    def widget(self, frame):
        self.lblNum1 = Label(frame, text="Primer Número: ",bg="yellow")
        self.txtNum1=Entry(frame, bg="pink")
        self.lblNum2 = Label(frame, text="Segundo Número: ",bg="yellow")
        self.txtNum2=Entry(frame, bg="pink")
        self.lblNum3 = Label(frame, text="Resultado: ",bg="yellow")
        self.txtNum3=Entry(frame, bg="cyan")
        self.lblNum1.place(x=10,y=10,width=100, height=30)
        self.txtNum1.place(x=120,y=10,width=100, height=30)
        self.lblNum2.place(x=10,y=50,width=100, height=30)
        self.txtNum2.place(x=120,y=50,width=100, height=30)
        self.lblNum3.place(x=10,y=120,width=100, height=30)
        self.txtNum3.place(x=120,y=120,width=100, height=30)
    
    def fSuma(self):
        n1=self.txtNum1.get()
        n2=self.txtNum2.get()
        r=float(n1)+float(n2)
        self.txtNum3.delete(0,'end')
        self.txtNum3.insert(0,r)

    def fResta(self):
        n1=self.txtNum1.get()
        n2=self.txtNum2.get()
        r=float(n1)-float(n2)
        self.txtNum3.delete(0,'end')
        self.txtNum3.insert(0,r)

    def fMultiplicacion(self):
        n1=self.txtNum1.get()
        n2=self.txtNum2.get()
        r=float(n1)*float(n2)
        self.txtNum3.delete(0,'end')
        self.txtNum3.insert(0,r)

    def fDivision(self):
        n1=self.txtNum1.get()
        n2=self.txtNum2.get()
        r=float(n1)/float(n2)
        self.txtNum3.delete(0,'end')
        self.txtNum3.insert(0,r)

root = Tk()
op = Op(root)
root.mainloop()**
```

Y el error:

```
r=float(n1)-float(n2)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Comment: Cuando creas los `frame` con la función `widget` utilizas los mismos campos `Entry` una y otra vez, por lo que al final las operaciones se van a realizar únicamente con los campos que están en la sección de "División".

Comment: Ya lo logre solucionar, muchas gracias

Comment: Buen día, para evitar tener preguntas abiertas sin respuesta es mejor si redactas una respuesta y su explicación o si cierras la pregunta. Saludos!